# Adding jquery on nodejs Serverside: Specifically using $.getJSON won't work on nodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, getjson

I'm trying to add Jquery on my server.js. I'm using windows 8 as my server. I'm performing a AJAX call with jquery on nodejs.
My server would actually load a JSON data from YAHOO. i got my port 5555

I run the commandprompt on and type

```
npm install jquery
```

Then:

```
node server.js
```

Here is my server.js

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var http                    = require("http")
, fs                        = require("fs")
, qs                        = require("querystring")
, port                  = 5555


var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

$.getJSON( 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from    yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = 'AAL'&format=jsonstore://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
    ', cbFunc);

});

function cbFunc(data){
console.log(data);
}

server.listen(port);

console.log('Server is listening to http://localhost/ on port ' + port + '...');
```

Anyone can help me in my problem. Thanks in advance!

Please ignore the URL because that's just a sample and its working on my YAHOO URL

Comment: Side note: sample you've shown have completely invalid Url (not necessary a reason to fail, but definitely not a good sample why particular code does not work).

Comment: Use [request](https://github.com/request/request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

npm install request

then:

```
var request = require('request');

request.get(myUrl, { json: true }, function(err, res) {
    // handle res data here
})
```